# How to disable padding at the top of NavigationView

Tags: c#, xaml, navigationview

How to disable padding at the top of NavigationView?

code:

```
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

But NavigationView content still leaves space on top:

[image: Screenshot NavigationView]